# Search function .match() case sensitive

Tags: javascript, vue.js

`this.items` is an array of objects. I am using this to search the items by the search bar, but `.match()` is case sensitive. For example, if I have an item called `Milk`, when I type `milk`, it won't come up.

How can I make this work for both lowercase and uppercase?
[Live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c0der9ja/)

```js
filteredOffers() {
    return this.items.filter((offer) => {
        return offer.title.match(this.search);
    });
},
```

I tried:

```js
offer.title.match(/this.search/i);
```

but it gives me a blank page.

Comment: you need to add regex in the first argument of `match()`, what's `this.search`?

Comment: it's a search field. I've added link with live view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the two terms to lowercase before comparing them:

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    filteredOffers() {
      const searchTerm = this.search.toLowerCase();
      return this.items.filter((offer) => {
        return offer.title.toLowerCase().match(searchTerm);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

```js
const items = [
  { title: 'Foo bar' },
  { title: 'The Milk Is Delicious' },
  { title: 'Baz qux' },
  { title: 'I drink chocolate milk' },
]

const search = 'milk'
const searchTerm = search.toLowerCase()
const result = items.filter((offer) => {
  return offer.title.toLowerCase().match(searchTerm)
})

console.log(result)
```